# Network Render Errno 2: No Such File or Directory

Tags: rendering, network

**FIRST**:

I'm on a Mac. I'm running 2.78.

**SECOND**:

Got the Network Rendering setup perfectly. I've sent jobs over my network. Once a job chunk is processed, the job fails due to ***Errno 2, No such file or directory [insert job directory file here]***.

**ATTEMPTS TO SOLVE**:

- Initially used /tmp/
- Switched to a directory I made on my Desktop
- Gave R/W permissions to ALL groups including "Everybody"
- Ran Blender from the command line in SUDO mode

**WHAT HAPPENS:**

The files are created on the Slave machine, but it throws an Errno 2 upon finishing a chunk. It looks like it's trying to access the EXR file to send it back to the Master.

I own several computers, and all of them are failing in exactly the same way.

Suggestions?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3EcpkwLCFI This is Moby Motion showing how to do this and he made key point about UNCLICK Overwrite and Click on Placeholder because this keeps track of what each machine has done. The tutorial is 9 minutes and wow cool